# Creating Portable Apps from installed Programmes

Tags: virtualization, portable-apps

I want to make an existing application on my laptop portable. From what I read, there are a number of applications that will do this but they all require that the application is a first-time install.

So, what can I do to get around this problem if the app is already installed? I know that uninstalling it will not completely removed from my computer and that some elements (mostly the registry) will remain so that these will not get picked up an incorporated in the stand-alone file.

Can anybody suggest how I might get around this problem without doing a clean install of my existing computer?

Many thanks,

Cameron

Answer (score 2):

### Depends on what app you installed.

The overall solution is to make an clean install of windows and the next time make the portable app inside a virtual machine like VMWARE or Oracle VirtualBox.

*As a side note:
 - Before making a portable app I always try to install them in a drive shared between the virtual machine and my computer, most of the time (usually in games) I can run the app using the installed files in the shared drive, outside the virtual machine.